# How can I connect to a Jabber group chat through a bookmark with jabber.el?

Tags: jabber, bookmarks

How can I connect to a group chat using a bookmark with jabber.el? I figured out how to *look* at the bookmarks via `M-x jabber-edit-bookmarks`, but I can't find any commands to actually use them! (Actually *editing* bookmarks seems unsupported, at least in my version of jabber.el.)

I have a few bookmarks already set up with another service that *do* show up in the Jabber bookmarks buffer, but I have no idea of how to actually connect through them.

Comment: I'd say you use `M-x jabber-chat-with` and give the name of the bookmark as jid; caveat: I don't use jabber.el, I just skimmed the sources because you made me curious :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a command for connecting to all bookmarked group chats that have the "autojoin" flag set: `M-x jabber-muc-autojoin`.  This is included in `jabber-post-connect-hooks` by default, so you should only need to use it just after modifying bookmarks.

You can join a room manually with `M-x jabber-muc-join`.  It currently doesn't offer the bookmarked rooms for completion (though it probably should), but if you enter the JID, it will pick up the nickname configured in the bookmark.

Editing bookmarks is supported by jabber.el, but sometimes the server doesn't allow it.  You should see an error message in the echo area in that case.

Comment: I did get an error message: `Storing bookmarks failed: Feature not implemented`. I thought it meant that it wasn't implemented in `jabber.el`, but I guess it could mean that it's not implemented on the server. I could also just have an old version of `jabber.el`.

Comment: Ah, I can see how that message is misleading.  It is actually just reporting what the server returned, but perhaps that could be made clearer...

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Server error messages are a pain. Perhaps it could just have a note that it's a server response? Something like `Jabber server error: Storing bookmarks failed: ...`.